# What is "defensive reference" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found this in d3:

```js
function d3_dispatch_event(dispatch) {
  var listeners = [],
      listenerByName = new d3_Map;

  function event() {
    var z = listeners, // defensive reference
        i = -1,
        n = z.length,
        l;
    while (++i < n) if (l = z[i].on) l.apply(this, arguments);
    return dispatch;
  }

  event.on = function(name, listener) {
...
```

[Link to a line on github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/event/dispatch.js#L40)

What does "defensive reference" mean here?

Comment: It has no meaning in JavaScript. It only has meaning to the author of that comment.

Comment: @squint nice catch (#58 line). Let me accept your answer if you'll create it, and remove this comment:).

Comment: I'm not entirely correct about that. It looks like that line is for a removal. While it would ensure that the remove item will still be accessible (I guess that's what they want), [line 63](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/event/dispatch.js#L63) does actually perform a `.push()` into `listeners`. However, since they cached the `.length` for the `while` loop, the added items won't be reached. So I guess it's just for the removal so that the removed handler will still fire. Go ahead and give an answer. I'm not sure that I've analysed all angles, and I need to get back to work! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem when implementing event system is to fire listeners right. Altering listener list while invoking callbacks may result in unexpected behavior.

For example, let's say there is 2 listeners listening to event `x`. Event `x` is triggered and system begins to loop listeners from `index 0` to `index 1`. Listener at `index 0` is fired first. Callback is invoked and that callback happens to remove listener at `index 1`. Loop will proceed and it tries to fire callback at `index 1`. Listener does not exist anymore and exception occurs.

This is really simplified example of what could go wrong when altering listener list while looping. Addments to list can be handled easily by calculating count of listeners before loop. Handling remove actions while looping is much more complicated.

In d3 every remove action from listener list will result in creating new array of listeners and giving that array as value for variable `listeners`.

```
listeners = listeners.slice(0, i = listeners.indexOf(l)).concat(listeners.slice(i + 1));
```

The original array of listeners is not changed so the loop will work, but a reference to the original array is lost. That's why `event` function creates local reference to it. By `defensive reference` author probably means creating temporary reference to current (before loop) value of `listeners` which holds even if value of `listeners` is changed in some point of the loop.